# In Fate Can you Generate Multiple Spin from One Roll?

Tags: fate, diaspora

The [Diaspora SRD](http://www.vsca.ca/Diaspora/diaspora-srd.html#shifts-and-spin) says

> If you exceed your opponent when you make a defensive roll that does not have any effect other than being a successful defense, you don't get shifts. Instead, for every three by which you exceed the attacking roll, you generate spin.

While it's own sidebar says

> Opposed
>
> attacker and defender roll dice and add skill.   Attacker result - defender result = shifts.  If negative 3 or lower, defender gets spin.

So, can you generate multiple "spin" on a successful defense, or only one.  If you can generate multiple can you use multiple spin on the same roll?

Answer (score 7):

> ### [Shifts and Spin](http://www.vsca.ca/Diaspora/diaspora-srd.html#shifts-and-spin)
>
> Instead, **for every three** by which you exceed the attacking roll, you generate spin.
>
> Players may use any spin accumulated by them or an ally to gain +1 on their roll. **Any number of spin points may be used** towards a given roll.

Diaspora lets you gain multiple spin and spend multiple spin.

(This is different from Spirit of the Century, in which you get spin by exceeding the attack by three or more and spend it on the party's next roll or lose it.)

Comment: You still lose spin if you don't use it, but the trigger is different. *"You need to use up spin by the time the turn comes back to whoever generated it – he's the last person that can take advantage."* (SRD, Shifts and Spin)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate multiple spin from the same roll. The text and the sidebar are intended to say the same thing but re-phrased.

You can have multiple spin from multiple rolls as long as they haven't expired.

If you have multiple spin tokens you can spend as many as you want.